# Why SO failed to offer a gold tag badge for this user?

Tags: discussion, tag-score

I really shocked on seeing the tag score part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) user. He provides 50 non-wiki answers on [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag with a total score of `2763`. But SO failed to give him a gold badge or even a silver badge for that particular tag. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Because he doesn't meet the requirements for a gold tag badge. You need to have 200 non-wiki answers in the tag in order to achieve gold, not *just* a score of 1,000. And this situation is *exactly* why the minimum answer requirements exists - to make sure users are actually actively participating in the tag and not just grabbing badges from one-off answers. [He has a single answer with 2,279 score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository/2432799?s=1|37.1870#2432799). A single answer doesn't really prove your knowledge of or extended participation in a subject area. It just means you provided *one* really good answer.

Comment: Wow. A full quarter of that users 82K rep comes from one question.

Comment: Well, that still leaves 60K of rep earned by other ways. No way he got that through review and wiki edits only.

Answer (score 8):

The requirements for tag badges are:

[image]

50 answers is not enough to meet the silver or gold requirements. The user will need at least 80 answers for the silver badge, and 200 for gold.

Comment: You beat me, so I edited in the image I had prepared. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @slugster That's fine, thanks!